# How to change an image when the window size changes in react

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design

I tried using ternary operator but it did not work

```
import cclogomobile from '../../assets/cc-logo-mobile.svg'
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export default function imag(){
return(
 <>
  <img src={(window.width>700)? {cclogo}:{cclogomobile}} alt="cclogo" />
 </>
)}
```

[image: this is what it showed when window.width>700]

Comment: `resize` event listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The react answer is correct but you really dont need to use an eventListener there is an html picture element that will do this for you.

```
<picture>
  <source media="(max-width: 700px)" srcset={cclogomobile} />
  <img src={cclogo} alt="cclogo" />
</picture>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an EventListener to look for event change if you want to include that functionality. Other than that, you just have to use `window.innerWidth` instead of `window.width` inside your component. Also make sure to import the other image you are using

```
import cclogomobile from '../../assets/cc-logo-mobile.svg'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'        

export default function Image() {
  const [largeScreen, setLargeScreen] = useState(false);
    
  useEffect(() => {
    // Handler to call on window resize
    function handleResize() {
       if (window.innerWidth>700) {
          setLargeScreen(true);
       }
    }
    
    // Add event listener
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    handleResize();
    
    // Remove event listener on cleanup
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
  }, []);
    
    return <img src={largeScreen ? {cclogo}:{cclogomobile}} alt="cclogo" />
}
```